# How do I copy a specific word/number from a TXT file using Batch?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I need to search for a specific number that comes after a string in a text file.
For example I have this data:

```
yyy = 80rr, xxx = 136rr, zzz = 95rr
```

and I want to copy the numbers that between `yyy` and `rr`, `xxx` and `rr`, `zzz` `rr`. Then I want to echo these numbers.
Is it possible?

Comment: Try asking this on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet, using purely Windows tools, is probably Powershell. One-liner:
In PS already:

```
$(sls '[0-9]+' filename.txt -allm).Matches.Value
```

From CMD.EXE:

```
powershell -c "$(sls '[0-9]+' test.txt -allm).Matches.Value"
```

For a text file (called `filename.txt`) containing just your line, this prints the following:

```
80
136
95
```

I tested it on files with multiple lines and multiple numbers per line, and it still works, printing each number on its own line. Now, if you have any other numbers in the file that you don't want to echo, they will get echoed too. To avoid that, we can just match on numbers that end in `rr`:

```
$(sls '[0-9]+rr' test.txt -allm).Matches | foreach {$_.Value.trim('r')}
```

or

```
powershell -c "$(sls '[0-9]+rr' test.txt -allm).Matches | foreach {$_.Value.trim('r')}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can use `gawk` command. I've done like this:

```
    echo "yyy = 80rr, xxx = 136rr, zzz = 95rr" | gawk '{ match($0, /.*= ([0-9]+).*= ([0-9]+).*= ([0-9]+)/, array); printf "%d %d %d\n",array[1], array[2], array[3]}';
```

The result was:

```
    80 136 95
```

In your case:

```
    cat file.txt | gawk '{ match($0, /.*= ([0-9]+).*= ([0-9]+).*= ([0-9]+)/, array); printf "%d %d %d\n",array[1], array[2], array[3]}';
```

Comment: This isn't helpful as he is using Windows.

Comment: It's not ideal, but it may be portable to Cygwin.

Comment: There's various gawk ports for windows. I have one that's part of the [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) toolkit installed on my machine